io.fabric8.api.fabricexception: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.checkoutconflictexception: checkout conflict with files
Hola, tengo un problema con un contenedor de Jboss Fuse.
Detalle:
Estoy desde un servidor en linux.
No hay mucha documentacion del proyecto, asi que estoy siguiendo las lineas que han dejado, por ello hay una linea donde dice que debo copiar un broker.xml y pegarlo a la ruta:
fuse\fuseBrk01-pro\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084\fabric\import\fabric\profiles\mq\base.profile

y luego usar este comando:
profile-edit --pid io.fabric8.mq.fabric.server-hq-broker/config=profile:bg-broker.xml mq-broker-masterslave.hq-broker

pero al aplicar esto, borra el archivo, y luego en la consola de log, ya sale que no encuentra el archivo.
he intentado editar el archivo manualmente pero sale este error:
io.fabric8.api.fabricexception: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.checkoutconflictexception: checkout conflict with files:fabric/profiles/mq/base.profile/broker.xml

adjunto screenshot:

